# Import excel file data in database with maatwebsite using queue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to import excel file to db using maatiswebsite. For that I am using queue because it would take some time to import file. I want to show user a quick message that "your file is being imported. we will inform you once it is done." But not able to do it.

QUEUE_DRIVER = database

Here is what I did so far -
Controller -

```
public function import(Request $request) 
{
    Excel::filter('chunk')->load($request->file('import_file')
            ->getRealPath())->chunk(250, function($reader)
    {
        ImportDistributor::dispatch(new ImportDistributor($reader->toArray()));
    });

    dd('your file is being imported. we will inform you once it is done.');

}
```

Job -

```
public function handle()
{
    if(isset($this->data) && !empty($this->data))
    {
        foreach($this->data as $data)
        {
            DB::table('user_details')->insert($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Model -

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserDetailsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_details';
}
```

I am not able to store data in user_details.

Comment: please share your model.

Comment: @Deepak show error

Comment: @LuckySaini I have updated question.

Comment: @JigneshJoisar Not getting any error, it's storing data to jobs table but not storing in user_details table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `$fillable` property in your model and add all the fields which you want to save to your database

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserDetailsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_details';
    protected $fillable = ["name", "etc", "etc1"];
}
```

**And in Job, change code to this.**

```
use App\UserDetailsModel;

public function handle()
{
    if(isset($this->data) && !empty($this->data))
    {
        foreach($this->data as $data)
        {
            UserDetailsModel::insert($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but nothing gets change.

Comment: if i change QUEUE_DRIVER to sync, it stores data in database table user_details

Answer (score 1):

If the import works fine when you use sync drive, that means you need to [run the queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker):

`php artisan queue:work`